# Kendo Gauge with multiple pointers angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo radial gauge with three pointers. I defined them in the same way as their example (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/radial-gauge/multiple-pointers).
The problem is I can't figure out how to assign values to all three pointers (it doesn't have to be in one call).
The way they do it in JQuery is with a .allValues function and I can't figure out what that does or how to do it in Angular.
Here's what I tried:

```
$scope.myGauge[1] = 50;
$scope.myGauge = [20, 50, 80];
```

They both seem to change only the first pointer and not the other two.
I also tried this but it just breaks the angular code.

```
$scope.myGauge.pointers[1].value(50);
$scope.myGauge.data("kendoRadialGauge).pointers[1].value(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave my gauge an id of "radial1" and was able to set each pointer this way. This is still using JQuery and basically makes my ng-model useless, but it works at least. If someone has an answer of how to do it with Angular then feel free to share otherwise this will do for now

```
$("#radial1").data("kendoRadialGauge").pointers[1].value(50)
```